# How to write repeating Regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regex for the following pattern in JavaScript:

> 1|dc35_custom|3;od;CZY;GL|2;ob;BNP;MT|4;sd;ABC;MT|5;ih;DFT;FR|6;oh;AQW;MT|7;ip;CAN;MT|8;op;CAR;MT|9;ec;SMO;GL|10;do;CZT;KU|

where

- the first part `1|dc35_custom|` is fixed.
- the second part onwards, the pattern repeats 9 times(i.e. `3;od;CZY;GL|  2;ob;BNP;MT|` and so on.

The 1st character in it ranges from 2-11 and should not repeat. For example `3` appears in the first pattern, so should not appear again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that "and so on"? Describe the pattern in words, if you can't describe it in regex.

Comment: So you want regex pattern to filter a number out and leave everything else intact? Show an example of the end result that you want.

Comment: Your input string is either out of sequence or pasted wrongly: `|3;od;CZY;GL|2;ob;BNP;MT|`

Comment: I don't think it is intended to be sorted -- it just can't repeat. But these are just such details that really need to be spelled out, not merely given by example.

Comment: "cannot repeat" bit cannot be done with regexp. You need to check uniqueness manually (by pulling them out with either an `.exec` loop, or by splitting and mapping).

Comment: As long as your `|` pipelines are inside parentheses, that which is outside of the parentheses will not be effected.

Comment: @Mario: It can check that one piece is not the same as another. It can't do it in a loop. Your code below only tests that non-first pieces are not the same as first, and says nothing about them being different from each other. Example: `1|dc35_custom|3;od;CZY;GL|2;ob;BNP;MT|2;sd;ABC;MT|2;ih;DFT;FR|2;oh;AQW;MT|2;ip;CAN;MT|2;op;CAR;MT|2;ec;SMO;GL|2;do;CZT;KU|` matches.

Comment: It would need to have 9 explicit copies of the pattern, each doing a negative lookahead for all that preceded. Possible, but verbose even for regex.

Comment: @Amadan you're absolutely right, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a lot of assumptions with this, but here's a crack at it:

```
1\|dc35_custom\|(([2-9]|10|11);[a-z]{2};[A-Z]{3};[A-Z]{2}\|){9}
```

### How it works

- `1\|dc35_custom\|` is just literal text, escaping the vertical bar operators
- `([2-9]|10|11)` will match any number from 2 to 11.
- `[a-z]{2}` will match two lowercase letters
- `[A-Z]{3}` will match three uppercase letters
- `[A-Z]{2}` will match two uppercase letters
- `{9}` looks for nine consecutive matches of the entire sequence enclosed in parentheses

It will not, as Amadan points out, check for uniqueness, because that's a bit beyond what regex is for.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky, but here you go

The regex: `/^1\|dc35_custom(?:\|([2-9]|1[01]);[a-z]{2};[A-Z]{1,3};[A-Z]{1,2}){9}\|$/`

and the Unit tests: https://regex101.com/r/lU6sJ6/2 (hit 'Unit Tests' on the left)

I assume the following:

1. the first group WILL ALWAYS BE THE SAME
2. The first part of the pattern `3;od;CZY;GL` is a number between 2-11 and NO NUMBER CAN REPEAT
3. The second part is lowercase letters a-z, exactly two of them
4. The third part is uppercase letters A-Z, between 1 and 3 ( the {1,3} thing, you can change it to {3} if it's exact)
5. The fourth and last part is between 1 and 2 uppercase letters A-Z